# Are these particular cases of the universal property of the coproduct and product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, universal-property

I was talking to a friend about the results presented [here](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2019/09/26/group-homomorphism-direct-product-1/) and [here](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2019/09/26/group-homomorphism-direct-product-2/).
He told me that these are particular cases of the universal property of the coproduct and of the product (in a category). I have learnt a bit about universal properties, but I can't see why what he says is true. For instance, those universal properties (that of a direct product of groups, for instance) don't mention anything about having isomoprhisms in some cases. So, could someone enlighthen me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the Cartesian product $A\times B$ of two groups $A,B$ with the projection maps $\pi_A,\,\pi_B$ satisfies the universal property:
whenever we have a similar diagram, i e. homomorphisms $f:C\to A,\ g:C\to B$, then there's a unique homomorphism $u:C\to A\times B$ which makes
$$f=\pi_A\circ u\ \text{ and }\ g=\pi_B\circ u\,.$$
Namely, this condition forces $u(c)=(f(c),\,g(c))$, and this also works for defining $u$.

One more important thing is that whenever an object $C$ with maps $f:C\to A,\ g:C\to B$ also satisfies the universal property, then $u$ above turns out to be an isomorphism, hence $C\cong A\times B$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So this is why, basically, the results I linked are just those universal properties written for finitely many groups. Since they hold for arbitrarily many groups, I think that this is why my friend claimed that those are just particular cases of the universal properties of the coproduct and product, right?

Comment: Ah yes, the same applies to any (not necessarily finite) number of objects. Then the diagrams are cones over that many objects.

Comment: Now I understand, I can see why the results I linked can be regarded as particular cases. Thank you!